# How to prepopulate custom fields by URL hacking?

Tags: javascript, button, button-overrides

I am able to copy and save a new custom object from a JS button in Account detail like this..

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js')}

 var fb=new sforce.SObject("Feedback__c");

  fb.Name='{!Opportunity.Name}';
  fb.Description__c='{!Account.AnnualRevenue}';

  result=sforce.connection.create([fb]);

  if(result[0].success=='true'){
  alert('A new feedback was created successfully');
  }
```

I tried this unsuccessfully...

```
    /apex/RedirectWithVariables?object=Feedback__c&Name=Opportunity.Name
```

So I am facing the following issues..

- I get a popup with success alert in the above code I tried.How would I redirect to the Feedback__c page after its creation?
- How would I approach to create a JS button to **prepopulate** Feedback__c fields from Account object through URL hacking only. I have tried jquery to prepoluate fixed values but url hacking seems to be more suitable and handy in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use URL hacking on a Visualforce page unless you have put some JavaScript in your page or controller code that will pull the values from the URL and use them to populate input fields or properties.

I'm not sure why you'd need to use a JavaScript button to pass parameters on a URL - a URL button would be a better choice as you don't have to manage the browser redirection yourself.

However, with a JavaScript button, all that happens is the JavaScript you provide is executed.  Your snippet above isn't valid JavaScript, its just a URL.  You are also adding the Opportunity.Name string literal rather than a merge field, and as an aside I'm not sure how Opportunity.Name would be accessible from an account detail page.

You'll need to change the window.location value to your URL to send the browser elsewhere and use merge syntax to pull values from the account. So something like:

```
window.location='/apex/RedirectWithVariables?object=Feedback__c&Name={!Account.Name}';
```

Comment: Thanks @bob-buzzard for replying. Can u tell me where do I need to put this code? Inside <script> tags in a visuaforce button?

Comment: You can just put it in a JavaScript button, as its valid javascript that will be executed when clicked.